# How can I set total Supply in this ERC20 Contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I copied and pasted the example ERC20 contract from openzeppelin, but for some reason i cant find out where i can set the TotalSupply.

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;

import "../../GSN/Context.sol";
import "./IERC20.sol";
import "../../math/SafeMath.sol";

contract ERC20 is Context, IERC20 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;
    uint8 private _decimals;

    constructor (string memory name_, string memory symbol_) public {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
        _decimals = 18;
    }

    function name() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"));
        return true;
    }

    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);

        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
        _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }

    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: burn from the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);

        _balances[account] = _balances[account].sub(amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance");
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(amount);
        emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

  
    function _setupDecimals(uint8 decimals_) internal {
        _decimals = decimals_;
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual { }
}
```

Im able to set the TokenName and Symbol and Decimals but i cant set the total supply

I also get a Unable to import "math/SafeMath.sol": File not found
I dont understand why they release a code that doesnt even work?
can someone please help me fix this

Comment: have a look at https://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/deploying-erc20-tokens-test-network/

Answer (score 3):

About the `SafeMath`:

Openzeppelin implements `SafeMath` in their project, so if you just copied `ERC20`, you missed the `SafeMath` implementation. If you clone the entire project, this problem will be solved.

About the `totalSupply`:

This implementation is an ERC20 mintable token. If you check the function `_mint` you will see that the `_totalSupply` is increased everytime you call this function. You start with 0, then if you mint 10 your total supply will be 10 and so on.

If you want to set your total supply you can change the constructor to enable you to set the `_totalSupply`:

```
constructor (string memory name_, string memory symbol_, uint256 totalSupply_) public {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
        _decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = totalSupply_;
        _balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, totalSupply_); // Optional
    }
```

You can also prevent minting to increase total supply removing the `_mint` function.